# Bootstrap Modal doesn't scroll with Select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a boostrap modal with a select2 dropdown inside:

```
<div id="add-event" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            ....

            <div class="organizer-options form-group id="organizer-search">
                <span>Hosted by:</span>
                <select class="form-control organizer-search" name="organizer-search" autocomplete="off">
                </select>
            </div>
```

I init the select2 in a separate JS file:

```
$(".organizer-search").select2({
    dropdownParent: $("#add-event"),
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    placeholder: "Select the host",
    ajax: {
        url: "/people/search",
        method: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        delay: 250,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                term: params.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function(data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        }
    }
});
```

I added the `dropdownParent: $("#add-event")` line to the select2 init because otherwise I am unable to focus on the select2 inside the modal. I have also tried `$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};` before initalizing all my modals.

Both of these enable focusing on the dropdown, but disable scrolling of the modal on mobile (chrome and firefox).

Comment: Give any fiddle/snippet.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1kw3p1mu/3/

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue, and if so, how? I'm running up against a similar problem, I believe.

Comment: @Jiveman No, I gave up :(

Comment: I ran into same issue, but when I open and close the select field the modal scrolls! it still a user experience bug. I also found a solution programmatically that to use function `$(selector).select2('open')` and then `$(selector).select2('close')`. it doesn't work for me but it may work for you. I'm still trying to solve it and I'll update you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in select2 options must have

```
dropdownParent: $(this).parent(),// That fix weird positioning select2 input
```

After that we doing little trick when select2 opening event. I realized if modal height smaller than window height when select2 opening no problem for scrolling even after need scrolling.

So we put overflow adjustments on select2 events. When opening select2 set modal body to no overflow, after select2 open set back to default.

```
    $(document).on("select2:opening", (e) => {
        $('.modal-body').css('overflow', 'visible');
    });
    $(document).on("select2:open", (e) => {
        $('.modal-body').css('overflow', 'auto');
    });
```

That will fix your problem.